# Javascript Console returns incorrect sorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I entered the following code into the chrome console.

```
var array = [25,7,8,41];
array.sort();
```

It returns `[25,41,7,8]`. What's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The sort() method sorts the items of an array.
>
> The sort order can be either alphabetic or numeric, and either
>   ascending (up) or descending (down).
>
> By default, the sort() method sorts the values as strings in
>   alphabetical and ascending order.
>
> This works well for strings ("Apple" comes before "Banana"). However,
>   if numbers are sorted as strings, "25" is bigger than "100", because
>   "2" is bigger than "1".
>
> Because of this, the sort() method will produce an incorrect result
>   when sorting numbers.

If you would like this to be corrected you can write a comparison function as the first parameter passed to the sort method. There is one listed in the reference!

EDIT: Posted here for future cases...

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
function myFunction() {
    points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    console.log(points);
}
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

Comment: Better source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @j08691 I disagree with the overall contention that W3Schools isn't 'up to snuff' when it comes to programming. It may have been true some time ago but it has been, from my point of view, very helpful, especially for the general concepts when starting out. But yes, MDN is a valuable resource as well :)

Comment: It's better than it was, I can agree with that, but I just can't endorse it as as good as, or better, than MDN.

Comment: @j08691 I would never endorse it as better than MDN. To me it has its place when it comes to simple communication of concepts. It does very well in that aspect I believe. Whereas, MDN, though it seems easy to understand once you know what you're looking at, I wouldn't send one of my coworkers there who aren't really familiar with coding because they might see the heading explaining params and get too intimidated.

Answer (score 1):

By default the sort method sorts elements alphabetically. To sort numerically just add a new method which handles numeric sorts (sortNumber, shown below) -

```
 function sortNumber(a,b) {
        return a - b;
    }

    var Array = [25 , 7 , 8 , 41];
    Array.sort(sortNumber);
```

source [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Everything in javascript is object by default and when you try to sort it is trying to sort it alphabetically.
You have to write your own compare function to sort them numerically 
check the following code snippet

```js
var array = [25,7,8,41];
array.sort(sortCompare);
function sortCompare(a,b){
  return a-b;
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort method sorts items of an array. Sort method by itself interprets items as strings. 
Since "2" in "25" is a lower number than "7" in "7", it returns that 25 is indexed before 7 for example. In order to sort numbers in ascending order user:

```
var array = [25,7,8,41];
array.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

Check [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_sort2) as well.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the other answers here with a solution to the problem you are facing-- from [MDN's array.sort page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> To compare numbers instead of strings, the compare function can simply subtract b from a. The following function will sort the array ascending (if it doesn't contain Infinity and NaN):

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}
```